# Error in postman:Could not get any response, even after turning off 'SSL certificate verification'

Tags: spring-boot, docker, postman

I get this error when trying to send a postman request to a spring boot app which is in a docker container.
I was able to do this earlier, before the latest update Version 7.3.4 for windows.

The Error:

> Could not get any response
> There was an error connecting to .

I Followed the following suggestions:

> - The server couldn't send a response: Ensure that the backend is working properly
> - Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked: Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General Proxy
>   configured incorrectly
> - Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
> - Request timeout: Change request timeout in Settings > General

**POST** request- localhost:8080/tiny/access
I've tried with the address of the container as well:
172.17.0.3:8080/tiny/access

I'm expecting this to give some response.
**Note:** When the application is run, on spring boot locally, requests can be made using postman, but not when tried with the running docker container.

Comment: Did you try debugging ? If you get a "Could not get any response" message from Postman native apps while sending your request, open Postman Console (View > Show Postman Console), resend the request and check for any error logs in the console.

Comment: @MebinJoe, Did you mean the container? I ran the container in debug mode, and it runs successfully.

Comment: Were you able to pull any logs from the app deployed in the container ?

Comment: @MebinJoe, yes, it says  'Started TinyRadiusOneLastTryApplication in 5.36 seconds' as usual. but doesn't trigger the controller when a request through postman is sent.

Comment: Check for postman logs.

Comment: @MebinJoe, Many thanks for the help. When I checked the postman logs, it gave me 'socket hang up' error, so I changed the port of the container  and ran. It worked.

Comment: Glad to help you. Always welcome :)